# Ruby on Rails guide (blog) error in 5.10

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm learning Ruby on Rails and to begin I'm making this little blog application via http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#showing-articles .
Now I'm at 5.10 where I need to add validation to the form so if the user adds a tittle with a length shorter than 5.

So this is my articles_controller.rb:

```
    class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @articles = Article.all
    end

    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
        #render plain: params[:article].inspect

        #@article = Article.new(params[:article])

        @article = Article.new(article_params)

        #@article.save
        if @article.save
            redirect_to @article
        else
            render 'new'
        end

        redirect_to @article
    end

    private
        def article_params
            params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
        end
end
```

And in this view I have an error (new.html.erb):

```
    <%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

I'm new to Ruby and rails so I hope I can get some help.

Comment: Marek Lipka gave you the correct answer. Several other things - in Ruby (and Rails) it is considered a good style to use indentation, consisting of 2 spaces (instead of 4). Also, in your create action in don't need the second `redirect_to @article`.

Comment: Yes it works now, thanks Marek Lipka. But can I have an explanation about why I need this line or what it does?

Comment: An why is it concidered to use indentation consisting of 2 spaces?

Comment: @GillisWerrebrouck I already gave you the explanation. You need this because it initializes `@article` variable, which is needed by you in your view.

Comment: 2-space indentation is simply a convention in Ruby that virtually everybody who program Ruby professionally follows.

Comment: @GillisWerrebrouck, you can have a look at https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide and https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide Also, make sure you have a solid foundation in Ruby, before learning Rails. Otherwise, you'll have hard time understading many things in Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't initialize `@article` instance variable, but you try tu use it in `new` view. You should have:

```
def new
  @article = Article.new
end
```